# Android context sub-menu opened-closed-reopened by itself

Tags: android, contextmenu, behavior, submenu

I have a context menu which include a sub-menu, when-ever I tap on the item to open the sub-menu, the sub-menu opens/closes and reopens quickly. That's very annoying but more problematic some of my users don't see the sub-menu at all, it opens/closes and that's it!

Now after experimenting I figured out that long-pressing the item actually works as soon as I release the item: the sub-menu opens properly and stays open!

So I decided to build a very basic project believing I had a bug in my app, created a new app with the wizard, a single activity, a single text on which I registerForContextMenu and a context menu with a simple sub-menu.

The issue reproduced itself immediately!!! Does anyone experience the same issue and could tell me what am I doing wrong? I believe I followed documentation and samples, but I can't find any information on this problem anywhere!!!

I've posted the issue on Google groups and reported as an issue on Android project, but so far no-one responded, here are the links to both which include the test project (not sure how I can attach a file here?).

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53239&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/SLteohmgyy0

Comment: Hello, anybody out there to provide some insight into this? This seems like basic stuff and I'm quite surprised no-one had this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I had to get rid of any sub-menu in context menu and instead open another context menu on item selection.

The following got rid of the flickering and ensured the sub-menu remained open. Had to use a spare hidden view to open the new context menu though.

```
    if (id == R.id.menu_item_for_sub_menu)
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                View v = vg.findViewById(R.id.fake_view_for_context);
                if (v != null)
                {
                    registerForContextMenu(v);
                    openContextMenu(v);
                    unregisterForContextMenu(v);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    }
```